# How to troubleshoot Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046' Permission denied?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, vbscript, ms-sql, asp

The line the error formulates from is: `Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(Server.MapPath(newfolderpath))`.

Here is the code below:

```
If Request.Form("add")= "true" then 

Dim prop, user, pwd, dir
prop    = ChkString(request.Form("Prop"))
user    = ChkString(request.Form("User"))
pswd    = ChkString(request.Form("Pswd"))
dir     = ChkString(request.Form("Dir"))

 Dim filesys, newfolder, newfolderpath
 newfolderpath = "/ppi/"& dir
 set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 If filesys.FolderExists(Server.MapPath(newfolderpath)) = true Then
  Response.Write("<center><br><br><span class='bodybigred'>Sorry, this folder already exists.</span><br><br><span class='bodybig'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Please try again</a></span><br><br><br><br><br><br></center>")
 Else
   Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(Server.MapPath(newfolderpath))
   SQL =    "INSERT INTO PPI " &_
            "   (Property_Name, Username, Passwd, PPI_Dir) " &_
            "VALUES ('" & prop & "','" & user & "','" & pswd & "','" & dir & "');"
   Conn.Execute SQL
   Conn.Close
   Set Conn = Nothing
   Set filesys = Nothing 
   Response.Redirect "ppi.asp?view=all&prop=" & prop & "&posted=true"
 End If
End If
```

Comment: What have you tried already in attempts to rectify the problem?  Does the user the script runs as have permission to create the folder in `/ppi/`?  Does `/ppi/` actually exist?

Comment: I created a new user with read and write permissions and ppi is a folder/directory that exists.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(Server.MapPath(newfolderpath))` line, and use a Watch to determine what the exact value of "newfolderpath" is at that point in the code.  What is it?

Comment: What do you mean re: watch?  How is that determined?

Comment: What are you using to debug this VBS?

Comment: I think that it is a server issue b/c the script was working on a linux machine and I have moved to a windows machine (windows server 2008 r2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added IUSR user and IIS_IUSRS (for IIS 7) to the directory/folder to set file system permissions.